# Get multiple rows into PHP URL

Tags: php, html

I'm wanting to make a URL that transfers all the placed product numbers (they are in multiple rows) from the cart into the URL to be passed to the next page. Not sure if this is possible!

I have tried making the URL with a variable:

```
$placeditems = $_POST['placeditems'];
$url = "myorder.php?id=".urlencode($placeditems);
```

As was requested in the comments, below is my coding for the entire file as of right now (with some edits from the suggested comments).

```
<?php
session_start();
$cart = $_COOKIE['crochetdamour'];
    if(isset($_POST['clear'])) {
        $expire = time() -60*60*24*7*365;
        setcookie("crochetdamour", $cart, $expire);
        header("Location:mycart.php");
    }
    if($cart && $_GET['id']) {
        $cart .= ',' . $_GET['id'];
        $expire = time() +60*60*24*7*365;
        setcookie("crochetdamour", $cart, $expire);
        header("Location:mycart.php");
    }
    if(!$cart && $_GET['id']) {
        $cart = $_GET['id'];
        $expire = time() +60*60*24*7*365;
        setcookie("crochetdamour", $cart, $expire);
        header("Location:mycart.php");
    }
    if($cart && $_GET['remove_id']) {
        $removed_item = $_GET['remove_id'];
        $arr = explode(",", $cart);
        unset($arr[$removed_item-1]);
        $new_cart = implode(",", $arr);
        $new_cart = rtrim($new_cart, ",");
        $expire = time() +60*60*24*7*365;
        setcookie("crochetdamour", $new_cart, $expire);
        header("Location:mycart.php");
    }
$placeditems = $_GET['placeditems'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Crochet d'Amour</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/kfn2dzo.css">
        <link href="SiteStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="clearfix">
            <img src="images/ball.png" alt="Ball of yarn." id="ball"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Crochet d'Amour" id="logo">
            <?php include('includes/nav.inc');?>
        </header>
        <div class="clearfix">
        <section style="width:100%;">
            <h1>My Cart</h1>
            <form method="get" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden">Product ID</th>
                    <th>Placed Items</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $cart = $_COOKIE['crochetdamour'];
                if ($cart) {
                    $i = 1;
                    include('includes/dbc.php');
                    $items = explode(',', $cart);
                    foreach($items AS $item) {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderplace WHERE orderplace_number = '$item'";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                        if($result == false){
                            $mysql_error = mysqli_error($con);
                            echo "There was a query error: $mysql_error";
                        }else {
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo '<tr><td align="left" id="prodid" name="prodid" class="hidden">' .$row['product_id']. '</td>';
                                echo '<td align="left"><input type="text" name="placeditems" id="placeditems" value="' .$row['orderplace_number']. '"></td>';
                                echo '<td align="left" id="prodname" name="prodname">' .$row['product_name']. '</td>';
                                echo '<td align="left" class="desctd" id="proddesc" name="proddesc">' .$row['product_size']. ', ' .$row['product_gender']. ', ' .$row['product_theme']. ', ' .$row['product_specs']. '</td>';
                                echo '<td align="left" id="prodprice" name="prodprice">' .$row['product_price']. '</td>';
                                echo '<td align="left"><a href="mycart.php?remove_id='.$i.'">Remove From Cart</a></td></tr>';
                                $sum += $row['product_price'];
                            }//end while
                            $i++;
                        }//end else
                    }//end foreach
                }//end if
                ?>
                <?php {echo '<tr><td align="right" colspan="5" style="font-size:110%;font-weight:400;" id="total" name="total">Total: ' .$sum. '</td></tr>';}
                $url = "myorder.php?id=".urlencode($placeditems)."&total=".urlencode($sum);?>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Empty Cart" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"> <?php if(isset($url)) {echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><input type="submit" name="order" value="Proceed with Order" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"></a>';} ?>
            </form>
        </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
                <p class="footerp">Copyright &copy; 2018-2019 Crochet d'Amour. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your form post a `GET` action.
if , lets say you have a couple of fields:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                <input name="test" type="text"/>
                <input name="test2" type="text"/>
                <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Empty Cart" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"> <?php if(isset($url)) {echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><input type="submit" name="order" value="Proceed with Order" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"></a>';} ?>
            </form>
```

It will produce a `GET` request with this params `?test=WATEVER_YOU_TYPED&test2=SECOND_FIELD&clear=Empty&20%Cart` or whatever is enterpret whitespace, i do not remember that.

Comment: This isn't getting all the rows. Thank you though!

Comment: You have to move your `form` declaration above all `inputs` to get it worked right

Comment: ABOVE DOCTYPE AND HEADER INFO: $placeditems = $_GET['placeditems'];
IN BODY:
<form method="get" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
..TABLE AND PHP INFO
echo '<td align="left"><input type="text" name="placeditems" id="placeditems" value="' .$row['orderplace_number']. '"></td>';
..MORE PHP INO
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Empty Cart" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"> <?php if(isset($url)) {echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><input type="submit" name="order" value="Proceed with Order" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"></a>';} ?>
            </form>

Comment: @jcarnes93 just post your entire php file to advise you in the right direction

Comment: Edited original post to include full file.

Comment: @jcarnes93 `<a href="'.$url.'"><input type="submit" name="order" value="Proceed with Order" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"></a>` What's that?

Comment: @jcarnes93 The input never should be enclosed within `a` tag

Comment: Oops! I accidentally changed that somehow. It's supposed to be <a href="'.$url.'"><input type="button" name="order" value="Proceed with Order" style="margin-left: 40px" class="emptycart"></a>